# iTunes sync "beep" loop iPhone and mac

Tags: macos, ios, itunes

About half the time i plug in my iPhone 6 to my MBP2015 15" to sync and they get stuck in a loop: the phone will beep to indicate the start of a sync, and the screen flashes, then 1 second later it beeps again. It keeps beeping until unplugged. Fully rebooting both devices at the same time seems to work, but its a pain... Rebooting either is not effective: they both need to be booted if the loop has happened.

Any tips on how I could further debug? Extract from console logs below for two "beep" cycles.

iOS 9.2.1 (13D15), OSX 10.11.3. All the latest updates installed.

```
10/02/16 8:35:55.972 AM iTunes[926]: Entered:_AMMuxedVersion2DeviceConnected, mux-device:80
10/02/16 8:35:55.974 AM iTunes[926]: tid:4217 - unable to query device capabilities
10/02/16 8:35:56.084 AM iTunes[926]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:80
10/02/16 8:35:56.084 AM iTunes[926]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:80
10/02/16 8:35:56.084 AM iTunes[926]: tid:4217 - BootedOS mode device disconnected
10/02/16 8:35:56.084 AM ath[978]: _receive_message (thread 0x7fff7f61a000): Far end closed connection: Resource temporarily unavailable
10/02/16 8:35:56.084 AM AppleMobileBackup[1034]: lockssl_handshake (thread 0x7fff7f61a000): SSL handshake controlled failure 0: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL (Early EOF reached)
10/02/16 8:35:56.085 AM iTunes[926]: _receive_message (thread 0x700000cdc000): Far end closed connection: Undefined error: 0
10/02/16 8:35:56.085 AM ath[978]: AMDeviceStartSession (thread 0x7fff7f61a000): Could not start session with device 9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269: kAMDDeviceDisconnectedError
10/02/16 8:35:56.085 AM AppleMobileBackup[1034]: AMDeviceStartSession (thread 0x7fff7f61a000): Could not start session with device 9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269: kAMDDeviceDisconnectedError
10/02/16 8:35:56.085 AM AppleMobileBackup[1034]: 1034:2137104384|DeviceLinkListener.c:_copyMobileDeviceValue| ERROR: Attempt to copy a value from an unpaired device. Cowardly refusing to do so.
10/02/16 8:35:56.086 AM iTunes[926]: AMDeviceStartSession (thread 0x700000cdc000): Could not start session with device 9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269: kAMDDeviceDisconnectedError
10/02/16 8:35:56.086 AM iTunes[926]: failed to connect to USB device 0x7fc076146350, UDID 9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269 (0xE8000084)
10/02/16 8:35:56.092 AM AppleMobileBackup[1034]: INFO: Device detached 0x7fa303d00b80/9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269
10/02/16 8:35:56.414 AM iTunes[926]: Entered:_AMMuxedVersion2DeviceConnected, mux-device:81
10/02/16 8:35:56.421 AM iTunes[926]: tid:14f2b - unable to query device capabilities
10/02/16 8:35:56.605 AM iTunes[926]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:81
10/02/16 8:35:56.605 AM iTunes[926]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:81
10/02/16 8:35:56.605 AM ath[978]: lockssl_handshake (thread 0x7fff7f61a000): SSL handshake controlled failure 0: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL (Early EOF reached)
10/02/16 8:35:56.606 AM AppleMobileBackup[1034]: lockssl_handshake (thread 0x7fff7f61a000): SSL handshake controlled failure 0: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL (Early EOF reached)
10/02/16 8:35:56.606 AM iTunes[926]: lockssl_handshake (thread 0x700000cdc000): SSL handshake controlled failure 0: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL (Early EOF reached)
10/02/16 8:35:56.606 AM iTunes[926]: tid:4217 - BootedOS mode device disconnected
10/02/16 8:35:56.606 AM ath[978]: AMDeviceStartSession (thread 0x7fff7f61a000): Could not start session with device 9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269: kAMDDeviceDisconnectedError
10/02/16 8:35:56.606 AM AppleMobileBackup[1034]: AMDeviceStartSession (thread 0x7fff7f61a000): Could not start session with device 9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269: kAMDDeviceDisconnectedError
10/02/16 8:35:56.606 AM AppleMobileBackup[1034]: 1034:2137104384|DeviceLinkListener.c:_copyMobileDeviceValue| ERROR: Could not start session with device: This device is no longer connected. (132)
10/02/16 8:35:56.606 AM iTunes[926]: AMDeviceStartSession (thread 0x700000cdc000): Could not start session with device 9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269: kAMDDeviceDisconnectedError
10/02/16 8:35:56.607 AM iTunes[926]: failed to connect to USB device 0x7fc070e52cc0, UDID 9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269 (0xE8000084)
10/02/16 8:35:56.607 AM AppleMobileBackup[1034]: INFO: Device detached 0x7fa303ea61b0/9a86d929e12afd57eb327ba220b13536a4ce8269
```

Comment: can you reformat your "quote" to "code" using Cmd/k instead of whatever you did; you didn't make it easy to rescue.

Comment: Does this only happen when connected to your mac? If you take the same cable and plug it into a power adapter, does it happen there as well?

Comment: only when connected direct to mac via usb/lightning cable

Comment: I'm having this issue now. Apple is total garbage these days. I HATE this company!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who follow: Looks like faulty USB ports on the MBP.

There are two ports: one persistently has the problem. The other will work most of the time if I insert the USB cable, then push / lightly twist the base of the plug horizontally in its socket so the outer end is leaning toward the rear of the computer. Possibly there is a slight misalignment of the pins? The cable is the original cable that came in the box with the iPhone 6

### Update: clean the socket with a toothpick

The problem grew gradually worse until I found https://www.cnet.com/how-to/use-a-toothpick-to-clean-out-your-iphone/ which described fluff in the lightning port on the phone. When I looked in to the socket, there did not seem to be anything in there. But when I scratched around with a toothpick a surprising amount of compacted fluff/dust/pocket lint was dislodged and came out. Now the lightning plug sits securely in the socket (it used to wobble). There is no "beep loop".

Comment: I am having exact issue. Did you fix it? My USB port works for all other purposes just not when connecting to my iPad and iPhone...

Comment: no solution: seems to be a physical connector thing. If I push the plug slightly horizontally in its socket either on the phone or the mac the beeping goes away. Sometimes it is unusable. Seems to happen on sync more often than on charge.

Comment: Sad to hear that... I can sometimes get it working on the right port of my MBP but it is not stable. I feel it is software issue because when vmware takes control of the USB it seems very stable. Too bad it is still not fixed by Apple after so many people complaint it so long...

Comment: @BryanChen can you post links to the other complaints for those who follow? thanks!

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5523411?start=0&tstart=0 and https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/iphone-repeatedly-disconnects-reconnects.500406/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: Your iPhone needs to be charged at least 50% in order to sync in iTunes. (My iPhone was charged at 45% and I got the dreaded beeping sound today. Absurd? Yes.) Once you charge it more fully, the beeping should cease. At least it did for me.